# Why does my Javascript calculator multiply the answer by 2 when pressing an operator following an equals press?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am working my way through The Odin Project and I'm currently stuck on the "Calculator" project.

For the most part, considering my current Javascript knowledge, I am happy with how it works. However; after outputting the result of a calculation by pressing the equals button, if I then press any of the mathematical operators if will then immediately multiply the displayed value by 2 and I can not figure out why.

The calculator can be found here: https://nortski78.github.io/calculator/

To reproduce the bug, enter 5 + 5 = + (that will display 20)

The parts of my code where I believe the problem lies is:

```
operatorButtons.forEach((operatorButton) => {
    operatorButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        setOperand(getDisplayValue());        
        setOperator(event.target.textContent);  
        clear = true;
    })
})

btnEquals.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    setOperand(getDisplayValue());
    operate(operator, firstOperand, secondOperand);
    clear = true;
})

function setOperand(operand){

    operand = parseFloat(operand);

    if(firstOperand === null) { firstOperand = operand; }
    else { 
        secondOperand = operand;
        clear = true;
        updateDisplay(operate(operator, firstOperand, secondOperand));
        firstOperand = getDisplayValue();
    }
}

function setOperator(digit){

    if(digit != "="){
        operator = digit;
    }
}

function operate(operator, num1, num2){

    switch(operator){
        case "+":
            return add(num1, num2);
            break;
        case "-":
            return subtract(num1, num2);
            break;
        case "*":
            return multiply(num1, num2);
            break;
        case "/":
            return divide(num1, num2);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can debug your code and inspect variables. It will clarify why this happens. I see a lot of global variables, which probably retain their values also after `=` is pressed. There is also a `clear` variable, and the only thing that happens with it, is that is set to `true`. Never is it checked. Seems useless. But now you will say there is more code... and that is the main problem with your question. This snippet of code is not revealing much. NB: essential content should be inside the question, not behind a link.

Comment: Clicking `+` calls `setOperand`. In there `if(firstOperand === null)` won’t be true, you already assigned a value to that variable before (when you processed the previous `+` button click), and it never gets “nulled” again anywhere. So this proceeds with assigning `secondOperand`, and then it calls `operate` wrapped in `updateDisplay`.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you! I nulled firstOperand in the equals button event listener and now it's working. Now, how do I mark this as the answer? lol

Comment: I made an answer out of the comment, so you can accept that one now if you like ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking `+` calls `setOperand`. In there `if(firstOperand === null)` won’t be true, you already assigned a value to that variable before (when you processed the previous `+` button click), and it never gets “nulled” again anywhere.

So this proceeds with assigning `secondOperand`, and then it calls `operate` wrapped in `updateDisplay`.

So after pressing `=`, you have to reset your first operand, so that when it goes through `setOperand` again, it will assign a new first operand first, and only perform the calculation & display update on the second operand.